# if a polynomial $P(x)\in \mathbb {Z} [x]$ is a power of $n$ for all integer values of x, then $P(x)$ is the $n$th power of a polynomial?

Tags: number-theory

How can I use Hilbert's irreducibility theorem to prove that if a polynomial $P(x)\in \mathbb {Z} [x]$ is a power of $n$ for all integer values of x, then $P(x)$ is the power of $n$ of a polynomial in $ \mathbb {Z} [x]$ ?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224881/polynomials-which-always-assume-perfect-power-values).

Comment: "Power of $n$" and "$n$'th power" do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, I'm not very good at English.